# Should I make my database adaptor class a singleton?

Tags: android, database, singleton

I am using the [database adaptor from devx.com](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1763?supportItem=4)

I was wondering if I should make it a singleton so I can easily use it from a number of different classes without having to worry about multiple instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your logic is valid, I dont think you should. Think of concurrencies, eg. class X is updating the database, and class Y is retreiving values from it at the same time . So you have 2 operations on the database at the same time; having a singleton shall prevent this, as the db connection needs to be closed/reopened .